# How do I programmatically set the sort field on a MongoDB query using the C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, sorting, mongodb-query

I have a collection of Tool objects, which I want to optionally filter, and return into a paginated table on a web page. I've got it working with the filter and the pagination, but I'm having trouble with the sort. I'm using an Angular Material table, which lets the user chose the sort field and direction at run time.

Using the MongoDB C# driver, I built a collection of tools which match theFilter, (fo = find options = case insensitive). Skip and Limit provide the pagination - I do know that's not necessarily efficient for big collections, that is not a concern here - and ToList sends it to the API.

```
tools = _tools.Find<Tool>(theFilter, fo)
    .Sort(Builders<Tool>.Sort.Descending(x => x.Description))
    .Skip(pageNo * pageSize)
    .Limit(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

In that example, the Sort call correctly sorts the collection in descending order by the description field. I need to be able, at run time, to chose a different field (e.g. `x.id`, `x.Name`, `x.location`, `x.whatever`), and to be able to switch between descending and ascending order.

Attempts to use MongoDB's syntax:

```
    .Sort("{ description: -1}")
```

fail, as does attempting to build a SortDefinition object using the field's name:

```
    private SortDefinition<T> BuildSortDefinition<T>(string fieldName, string sortDirection)
    {
        FieldDefinition<T> theField = new StringFieldDefinition<T>(fieldName);
        SortDefinition<T> theSort;

        if (sortDirection.ToLower() == "desc")
            theSort = Builders<T>.Sort.Descending(theField);
        else
            theSort = Builders<T>.Sort.Ascending(theField);

        return theSort;
    }
```

I've only been able to make Sort work if I use a lambda expression. How can I either fix the lambda expression to use a configurable field; or use the `.Sort` properly in order to use a configurable field, in this scenario?

Comment: Just in case it's relevant, I'm using Mongo v3.4.10, and the driver is MongoDB.Driver v2.9.1.

Comment: not sure if it'll help but you can just do `Builders<T>.Sort.Ascending(fieldName);` instead of using `StringFieldDefinition` because `FieldDefinition` has an implicit operator that takes care of converting a string to the correct FieldDefinition type.

Comment: Unfortunately, it behaved in exactly the same way; no sorting. I also added indexes to each of the fields I was likely to sort by, no luck there either.

Comment: profile the db and see what commands get sent to mongo when you use lambda vs. string fields. if the driver doesn't generate the same command, then that's a problem with the driver. in a mongo shell, turn profiling on with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` and then run your c# code and then issue `db.system.profile.find().skip(1).limit(6).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()` which will show you the last 5 queries received by mongo server.

Comment: Thanks - that showed me the way.... answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was using the wrong casing for the search field - "description" instead of "Description".  Once I passed the correct case, it worked fine.